# Adding custom functionality to WYSIHTML5

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-family, wysihtml5

Hi am loving wysihtml5 but I need to be able to edit the font family via a list I define and I can't find a way to do this anywhere.

Is there a simple way to do this? Or indeed a difficult way??

Comment: Any update on this question?

Comment: I used TinyMCE instead... much better documentation and easier to customize.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I will keep it in mind :)